# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/datasources/JavaBytesEncoder$

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError on JavaBytesEncoder from Spark job which simply reads data from HBase table.

I'm using hbase-connectors library (https://github.com/apache/hbase-connectors). Spark version is 2.4, Scala version 2.11.8, and testing on Cloudera cluster. 
I looked at inside the hbase-spark jar and found JavaBytesEncoder$ class there. So I don't know why I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.toFilter(ProtobufUtil.java:1610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.toScan(ProtobufUtil.java:1155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.newRegionScanner(RSRpcServices.java:2964)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:3298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:42002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:304)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.toFilter(ProtobufUtil.java:1606)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/datasources/JavaBytesEncoder$
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.datasources.JavaBytesEncoder.create(JavaBytesEncoder.scala)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.SparkSQLPushDownFilter.parseFrom(SparkSQLPushDownFilter.java:197)
    ... 13 more

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.instantiateException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteWithExtrasException.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.makeIOExceptionOfException(ProtobufUtil.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.handleRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:350)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.rpcCall(ScannerCallable.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.rpcCall(ScannerCallable.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.call(RegionServerCallable.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:361)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It seems to be an error in HBase region servers trying to filter data because of Spark pushing down filters. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/HBASE/issues/HBASE-22769

Answer (score -2):

put SparkHbase_Connector.jar under Hbase/lib

Comment: please add some explanation for the future readers